# Find an option tag with 'selected' attribute with robot framework

Tags: xpath, automated-tests, robotframework

The application under text includes these option tags:

```
<option value="0" selected>Page 1</option>
<option value="1">Page 2</option>
<option value="2">Page 3</option>
```

etc.

Using Robot Framework, I would like to create a locator to find the option tag that contains or ends with "selected"
So far I've not been able to get one to work.

XPath for the selected option above is:

```
//*[@id="sfpagingation-dropdown"]/option[1]
```

CSS for same selcted option is:

```
#sfpagingation-dropdown > option:nth-child(1)
```

Maybe it's not possible?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out, or at least, I have something that seems to be working:

```
${SELECTED}=  xpath=//option[@selected=""]
```

"Wait until page contains element" is also necessary

Comment: Yep, that's good; technically you don't need the value comparison, so it can be `//option[@selected]` - which literary reads "all option tags having the attribute selected". And the most unambiguous version is `//option[boolean(@selected)]``. Good job!